# Permission Denied using save -append in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I'm getting the following error while saving the file in **MATLAB**

> ??? Error using ==> save
>   Unable to write file char_database.dat: permission denied.

```
save('char_database.dat','data','-append');
```

The file is created in the beginning and the same file is appended with the new data's for each iteration.

What could be the reason for this problem?

There are no issues with regard to permissions since saving file worked absolutely fine before.

Comment: There is *obviously* an issue with regards to permissions ...

Comment: Do you have the file opened during the process? I've experienced the very close kind of trouble when I was doing sound synthesis with the wav opened in a player.

Comment: Basically your Operating System (e.g. Windows) is not allowing Matlab to touch the file. That can be because you dont have permision to write in the place where the file is or (as Victor suggested) because there is some other process that is using the file at that moment.

Comment: Thanks Ratbert my question is If it was related to permission issue, why did it worked before?

Comment: That exactly answers my question. Thanks Victor and Ander